# The old file names are in Column A and new file names are in Column B, how to replace the old ones with new ones in the directory using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file that has two columns, column A & Column B.

The column A is "Path and filenames that had been selected", which has path of each file name in a network directory:

```
\\xxx\yyyy\gggg\ooo.pdf
\\xxx\yyyy\gggg\ogh.pdf
\\xxx\yyyy\gggg\pjo.pdf
```

The column B has "new file names", which are supposed to replace old file names (ooo.pdf, ogh.pdf, pjo.pdf):

```
fff.pdf
fgh.pdf
hjk.pdf
```

I have a code that is supposed to rename the old file names with new file names, but somehow it is not working effectively. PLease let me know what is wrong with the below code :

```
Sub RenameFiles()
Dim xDir As String
Dim xFile As String
Dim xRow As Long
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
If .Show = -1 Then
    xDir = .SelectedItems(1)
    xFile = Dir(xDir & Application.PathSeparator & "*")
    Do Until xFile = ""
        xRow = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        xRow = Application.Match(xFile, Range("A:A"), 0)
        If xRow > 0 Then
            Name xDir & Application.PathSeparator & xFile As _
            xDir & Application.PathSeparator & Cells(xRow, "B").Value
        End If
        xFile = Dir
    Loop
End If
End With
End Sub
```

Please let me know the VBA code that can replace the old file name with the new file name in the directory.

Comment: Use the `Name` command (`Name oldfile As newfile`)

Comment: @YowE3K I guess, OP needs to rename files *in Excel* rather *OS* :)

Comment: @YowE3K It would be really useful to me if you can let me know the full logic. Thanks.

Comment: @YowE3K I know what is `Name`. Does OP need to rename in Excel or OS?

Comment: @YowE3K. FYI, I have a logic already for the column B to rename filenames, but the logic isn't working right. Please suggest me changes to the existing code, if you have any. Thanks.

Comment: @YowE3K Oops! My bad! Didn't see changes :(

Comment: @JohnyL, It would be excel, because I am trying to rename file names in the network directory using Excel VBA

Comment: @YowE3K Ahaha))

Comment: @YowE3K Any suggestions?

Comment: @user9070221 What part of the code isn't working - my quick read of it makes me think it should work OK.

Comment: `not working effectively` as in a) Its slow. b) file names are not changed c) I am getting an error. ..........or something else?

Comment: @cyboashu I mean the code isn't working effectively because the folder names hasn't changed , even though the old names are in Column A and new names are in column B. Thanks.

Comment: @user9070221 Are you able to move files manually to the target directory? If so, your code should work. Also, do you have network security that might be hindering changes on network files through automation?

Answer (score 1):

You could use FileSystemObject:

```
Sub Iterator()

    'Tools -> References -> Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim fl As File
    Dim r As Long

    For r = 1 To 3
        Set fl = fso.GetFile(Cells(r, "A")) 'Path is taken from column "A"
        fl.Name = Cells(r, "B") 'Rename with name taken from column B
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do this code work if I want to rename multiple filenames and the source directory is a network directory?

Comment: @user9070221 Yes. Just use loop as set `File` object and rename it.

Comment: FYI, the code shows no error but it doesn't change anything as well.

Comment: @user9070221 I updated the code. The code works for me. I tested it on shared folder.